# implement a load spinner when submitting a form in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a load spinner when I submit a form. since I'm new to this whole react thing, I need some help.

What i exactly want is, When I click on the submit button it should show the load spinner, then load the table. now it shows the spinner even before clicking the submit button.

here's my code

```
    import React from "react";
import { LineWave } from "react-loader-spinner";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Table from "./Table";
function Main() {

     const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])
     const [formInputData, setformInputData] = useState(
          {
               Name: '',
               email: '',
          }
     );
     const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
     useEffect(() => {
          setloading(true)
          setTimeout(() => {
               setloading(false)

          }, 4000)
     }, [])

     const handleChange = (evnt) => {
          const newInput = (data) => ({ ...data, [evnt.target.name]: evnt.target.value })
          setformInputData(newInput)
     }

     const handleSubmit = (evnt) => {
          evnt.preventDefault();
          const checkEmptyInput = !Object.values(formInputData).every(res => res === "")
          if (checkEmptyInput) {
               const newData = (data) => ([...data, formInputData])
               setTableData(newData);
               const emptyInput = { Name: '', email: '' }
               setformInputData(emptyInput)

          }
     }

     return (
          <div className="container">
               <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-8">
                         <div className="col">
                              <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={formInputData.Name} name="Name" className="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                         </div>
                         <div className="col">
                              <input type="email" onChange={handleChange} value={formInputData.email} name="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" />
                         </div>
                         <div className="col">
                              <input type="submit" id="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} className="btn btn-primary" />
                              {
                                   loading ?

                                        <LineWave color={'#062DF6'} loading={loading} size={50} />
                                        :

                                        <Table tableData={tableData} />
                              }
                         </div>
                         <div className="app">

                         </div>

                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
     );
}
export default Main;
```

my table.js

```
    function Table({ tableData }) {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            {
                <table className="table" id='table'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.N</th>
                            <th>Full Name</th>
                            <th>Email Address</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            tableData.map((data, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={index}>
                                        <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                        <td>{data.Name}</td>
                                        <td>{data.email}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
export default Table;
```

Comment: Why are initially showing loader in useEffect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try once with following code

```
import React from "react";
import { LineWave } from "react-loader-spinner";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Table from "./Table";
function Main() {

     const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])
     const [formInputData, setformInputData] = useState(
          {
               Name: '',
               email: '',
          }
     );
     const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
   
     const handleChange = (evnt) => {
          const newInput = (data) => ({ ...data, [evnt.target.name]: evnt.target.value })
          setformInputData(newInput)
     }

     const handleSubmit = (evnt) => {
          setloading(true)
          evnt.preventDefault();
          const checkEmptyInput = !Object.values(formInputData).every(res => res === "")
          if (checkEmptyInput) {
               const newData = (data) => ([...data, formInputData])
               setTableData(newData);
               const emptyInput = { Name: '', email: '' }
               setformInputData(emptyInput)
      
          }
          setTimeout(() => {
               setloading(false)
          }, 4000)
     }

     return (
          <div className="container">
               <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-8">
                         <div className="col">
                              <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={formInputData.Name} name="Name" className="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                         </div>
                         <div className="col">
                              <input type="email" onChange={handleChange} value={formInputData.email} name="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" />
                         </div>
                         <div className="col">
                              <input type="submit" id="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} className="btn btn-primary" />
                              {
                                   loading ?

                                        <LineWave color={'#062DF6'} loading={loading} size={50} />
                                        :

                                        <Table tableData={tableData} />
                              }
                         </div>
                         <div className="app">

                         </div>

                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
     );
}
export default Main;
```

Comment: It works fine but doesn't show the spinner. it just shows the table

Comment: thank you I just did the same, before seeing your updated code. it works perfectly.

Comment: Note that you don't need to show any loader in your case as you are not submitting data to API. Loader is used only when you use any async/await function in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove useEffect code
and update handleSubmit with following code

```
       const handleSubmit = (evnt) => {
          evnt.preventDefault();
         setloading(true)
          const checkEmptyInput = !Object.values(formInputData).every(res => res === "")
          if (checkEmptyInput) {
               const newData = (data) => ([...data, formInputData])
               setTableData(newData);
               const emptyInput = { Name: '', email: '' }
               setformInputData(emptyInput)

          }
         setLoading(false)
     }
```